# Sublime Text projects on both Mac and Windows

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, dropbox

I'm not sure if this is possible or been done before but...

I jump between a Windows and Mac Sublime Text 2 IDE.  My active projects are stored in a Dropbox folder that is synced between my Windows machines.  Tonight I opened up Sublime on my OSX Maverick machine hoping to pound out some code.  Of course the project file wasn't able to find my Windows path and open the folders needed.  I opened the project file and see my windows path being specified.

```
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "/C/Users/me/Documents/Dropbox/Development/Projects/Active/folder"
    }
]
```

Is it possible to specify the mac folder in the same project file?  Am I missing something very simple?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were multiple threads started on ST forums, I will post a few of them where you may find suggestions that may help, but there are no ways to do this but keeping the path relative to the `.sublime-project` file. You may keep it in the directory where your project resides and point to it with `"path": "."`.

https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=14601
http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=57728
https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15278

As ST devs are very quiet right now I doubt it will be changed before the ST3 release.

Comment: Ahhh thank you!  It never occurred to me to set a relative path in the project file.  All my project files are in their respective project folder root so this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using sublime text 3.

Creating a folder structure with sublime in Windows it looks like this:

{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "C:\Dropbox\workspace\01_snippets\os"
        },
    ]
}

The only way to get it running on a mac and win is
* using relative paths
* to change from \ to /